# Creating an Object and Using it in a Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Say we have a class called `Maze`. Now suppose that we have another class called `MazeSolver`. So in order to create the `Maze` object in `MazeSolver` for the reason of using the methods from Maze, we create `private Maze maze`. Then within the constructor of `MazeSolver`, we also write `public MazeSolver(Maze maze)`. My question is, why do we have to do both? What is the philosophy behind the idea? Why can't we do one or the other opposed to doing both is I guess where I am confused.

Answer (score 4):

Well there is the field/variable where the Maze reference is stored:

```
private Maze maze;
```

And there is the constructor where the Maze reference is passed and set

```
public MazeSolver(Maze maze) { this.maze = maze; }
```

Beyond that, you need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two options 
first one is you can use like this

```
public MazeSolver(Maze maze) { 
this.maze = maze; 
}
```

second option is

```
public MazeSolver() { 
maze = new maza();; 
}
```

Actually your requirement is you need to use maza behavior so in that case you need one instance of maza class( if those method are non-static). that's why you need to initialize or you assign object to maza

I hope this will help you to understand your requirement